# Error when trying to create a Controller for web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller

I keep getting this error, as showing in the screenshot below when I try adding a controller.
Any help in regards to resolving this error will be greatly appreciated.

http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/Error/API_error_zpswocovwbw.jpg

Comment: Could you copy and paste (or type) the error and the code causing it into your actual question? It is small and blurry in your picture, but you should paste it in your question even if it was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stated that those entities (e.g. `Firearm`, `FirearmDescription`) have no key defined.

I can see you defined `itemID`. However, by convention this will not be used as the primary key unless you either

1. Rename the field to `FirearmId` **or,**
2. Add a `[Key]` attribute as below:

   ```
   [Key]
   public int itemID {get; set;}
   ```

You may learn more about the convention here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Key

Comment: Thank you, Good Sir. 
You fixed my issues, and also provided me with a better understanding on the issue.